# Can't compile with references c# mcs

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, mono

I'm trying to compile something with mono with references but for some reason it throws out nonsense errors(I can compile with visual studio, not with mono).

make script:

```
#!/bin/bash
SAVEPATH="/usr/home/"
LIBPATH="usr/home/source/lib"
REFS=( "MySql.Data.dll" "MySql.Web.dll" )
MAKEFILES=( "Main.cs" "HandleCallback.cs" "Logs.cs" "Database.cs")
CMDCOMPILE="mcs"
for element in "${REFS[@]}"; do
    CMDCOMPILE=$CMDCOMPILE" -reference:$LIBPATH/$element "
done
for element in "${MAKEFILES[@]}"; do
    CMDCOMPILE=$CMDCOMPILE" $element "
done
eval $CMDCOMPILE
mv /usr/home/source/Main.exe $SAVEPATH/Server
```

The result errors are

```
Database.cs(24,65): error CS1010: Newline in constant
Database.cs(25,0): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `3306'
Database.cs(25,8): error CS1010: Newline in constant
Database.cs(26,16): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `return'
Database.cs(54,68): error CS1010: Newline in constant
Database.cs(55,0): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `trying'
Database.cs(55,49): error CS1010: Newline in constant
Database.cs(56,13): error CS1002: ; expected
Database.cs(75,68): error CS1010: Newline in constant
Database.cs(76,0): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `trying'
Database.cs(76,47): error CS1010: Newline in constant
```

And like I said, there are no errors in Database.cs. I assume its giving me this because the "-reference:" tag is not doing its job.

The final command output

```
mcs -reference:usr/home/source/lib/MySql.Data.dll -reference:usr/home/source/lib/MySql.Web.dll Main.cs HandleCallback.cs Logs.cs Database.cs
```

Is the command incorrect or is something else missing?

Database.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Server
{
    public static class Database
    {
        private static MySqlConnection conn;

        public static bool ConnectDB()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Database...");
            string connString = "Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Port=3306;Uid=xxxx;password=xxxxxxx";
            conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to Database");
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Couldn't connect to database:");
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                return false;
            }
        }

        private static bool isAlive()
        {
            if (conn != null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        (...)
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your source

Comment: Claims of no errors in Database.cs notwithstanding, could you post line 20-30 anyway?

Comment: yep, added source

Comment: Are those the actual strings (other than the obfuscated connection string)? You don't have localized strings anywhere? Ie. those "Connected to Database" strings, those are actually written like that and not in some other language? If they were then this could be an encoding problem that Visual Studio/MSBuild/CSC handles that MCS doesn't.

Comment: Are you editing the code in Linux or macOS, or just on Windows?  Just trying to think of things that could give you newline problems...

Comment: No, they're in english.
@adv12 I'm writing it in visual studio and just moving the files over to a server

Comment: Is the server running Linux or macOS?

Comment: Look, the first error happens on `Port=3306` from the connection string, so I assume you have a `\r` in that string. Edit the file on linux with nano or something similar and rewrite the connection string, that should solve the errors.

Comment: adv12 linux
@Gusman Yes you are right, there was several new lines in the file, removing those fixed the issue.